# Same background color n bars backwards

Tags: pine-script

I want to color the background of my Traingview chart, e.g. red, `n` bars backwards. How do I do that?

Attempts (irrespective of time):

```
study(title="DbgRed", shorttitle="", overlay=true)
bgcolor(color.red, transp=75)
```

I can't find the answer in the user manual or via Google search.

How do I color the background and add coloring of `n` bars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `show_last` argument to trail the bgcolor by x bars.

```
//@version=4
study(title="DbgRed", shorttitle="", overlay=true)
bgcolor(color.red, transp=75, show_last = 25)
```

Cheers, and best of luck